# Python and mechanize issues (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, mechanize-python

Ok, so I just installed `mechanize` with `easy_install` from the command prompt, but now when I try to write a little snippet of code to test it, Python is telling me it can't import `mechanize`, any idea what might be going wrong?  I'm at a loss and unfamiliar with `mechanize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, I had placed my .py file in a new folder within the Python27 folder and apparently that was the issue.  I moved it to Python27 and it's correctly importing.